# Get all roots of a 6th degree polynom numerical

Tags: roots

I have a polynomial of the 6th degree. For this Polynom, I want to get all real roots. My problem is that all the Methods I read about are only to get one root. 
Is there a way how I could get all the roots?

For example: With a polynom of 5th degree I can get the derivation. Solve it explicit and then use the solutions to get the intervals for the Newton Method.

Is there maybe also a way to solve this problem with a polynomial of 6th degree?

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Why not just do it as for the degree 5 polynomials? Compute derivatives, find zeros as you did before, then you have the intervals.

Comment: Would [this](https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/html?q=polynomial%20root%20finding%20algorithms) help?

Comment: @M.Winter Because if i take the derivative i get an polynom of 5th degree. Then i have to solve this polynom again numerical :/ I think it's possible but i thought that maybe there would be a faster solution.  @a concernced citizien i cannot reach the website from your link.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Can you please not post an onion link?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for the answer. I read about this Method but the problem here is that i have to create an Matlab implementation. I searched for an Matlab Implementation but there was only Python and c++. And i doubt it that i am able to translate this code to an Matlab Code because it seems really complicated. There is also the possibility to use the mex function of Matlab but i want to use only Matlab skripts without other implementations. That's why i want to try to solve this problem with "easy" Methods

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen. it seems that you diud not choose the most appropriate user name. Please, do not play this game on this site.

Comment: I am afraid that there is nothing really simple. What you could do is to find one root (try to bracket a root) and then deflate the polynomial.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sorry for the link, I thought I grabbed the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) link (the former link is to duckduckgo.onion, and the search phrase is what is seen). Why do you say that about the username? What games are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The [Durand-Kerner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method) and [Aberth-Ehrlich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberth_method) methods find all roots simultaneously and are as easy to implement as [Newton’s method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Both methods are mentioned on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) overview page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read also about this methods but after some research i found that the Durand Kerner Method is unstable and doesn't converge everytime

Comment: Have you tried it? I haven’t come across a situation where it did not give all roots. You should take care to start with “random” initial complex roots. If all roots are known to be real then you can start with random real initial roots. The Aberth method converges quite a bit faster though in my experience.